# What are some natural arithmetical statements independent of ZFC?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory, meta-math

Gödel's first incompleteness theorem produces a statement in the language of arithmetic that's independent of a given theory. The second theorem says that a consistient theory can not prove its own consistency, which is also a arithmetical statement (since you phrase it in terms of a Turing machine that looks for contradictions, for example).

Are there any "natural" statements in arithmetic that are independent of ZFC (besides consistency of ZFC, which is arguably pretty natural)? The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC#Number_theory) only lists the consistency of ZFC.

Comment: And would that independence be proved using ZFC?

Comment: @GEdgar Probably ZFC + Con(ZFC). (You can't prove anything independent of ZFC using just ZFC.) Doing it with PA + Con(ZFC) would be even better, but is not required.

Comment: Two points: **(1)** "Independent" somehow (implicitly) implies that the statement could not be proved or disproved, or rather that both assuming the statement or its negation are equiconsistent with ZFC, this is certainly not the case with Con(ZFC). I would simply say "unprovable from ZFC" rather than "independent of ZFC". **(2)** Harvey Friedman has done a lot of work about producing arithmetic statements which are equiconsistent with large cardinals, there are also Laver tables, and of course as was recently shown the exact value of Busy Beaver for numbers above 8,000.

Comment: @Asaf 8000 is surprisingly small.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't quite get your comment - I would certainly say that $Con(ZFC)$ is independent of $ZFC$.

Comment: @Noah: Interesting, have you published your proof that $\sf ZFC$ doesn't outright prove $\lnot\operatorname{Con}\sf(ZFC)$? :)

Comment: @Matt: Indeed so, http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725

Answer (score 4):

Well, "natural" is obviously very subjective, but Harvey Friedman has done a lot of work recently on innocuous-seeming combinatorial principles which imply the consistency of large cardinals.

He's organized these by *templates* which generate a number of such statements within a given topic. He has [a number of manuscripts](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/foundational-adventures/downloadable-manuscripts/) on these topics, including

- [Boolean relation theory](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/foundational-adventures/boolean-relation-theory-book/)
- [Strong Ramsey theorems for finite trees](http://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/FinTreNec98-1ia73bv.pdf)
- [Invariant maximality](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/CMI051114w-p1qetc.pdf)

You may also be interested in his numerous posts to the [Foundations of Mathematics mailing list](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/mailman/listinfo/fom), the archives of which are searchable.

Comment: If we show in ZFC that an arithmetic problem is independent in internally defined ZFC then won’t the problem be true in the external ZFC, and wouldn’t we have a contradiction?