# Which "natural" problems are independent of ZFC?

Tags: logic, math-history, big-list, incompleteness, decidability

This question extends [What are some natural arithmetical statements independent of ZFC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974557/what-are-some-natural-arithmetical-statements-independent-of-zfc) beyond the realm of just number theory.

Scott Aaronson has pointed out that it's surprising how rarely the "Godelian gremlin" rears its head - that is, it's very rare for a problem of mathematical interest to end up being undecidable within ZFC, without having been specifically constructed to be.  What problems/conjectures were proposed strictly *before* being shown to be independent of ZFC?  The only examples that I'm aware of are [Hilbert's second problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_second_problem), the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), [Suslin's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem), [Kaplansky's conjecture on Banach algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky%27s_conjecture), and the [Whitehead problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem).  (Five examples may seem like a lot, but this is of course a vanishingly small fraction of all mathematical problems that have *ever* been posed.)

Comment: Independent, or provably independent from ZFC? For example, the existence of inaccessible cardinals is not provable, but possibly refutable. Does it count?

Comment: There are some nice examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/what-are-some-reasonable-sounding-statements-that-are-independent-of-zfc/6594#6594)

Comment: There are likely to be plenty of problems that are independent of ZFC, but not **provably** independent of ZFC.  And we'll never know which ones they are.

Comment: @JairTaylor Those are helpful examples, but I suspect that most of them were first discussed in the context of their independence, and therefore technically don't meet the requirements of my question :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good clarification question.  I suppose I mean provably independent, since as Robert Israel points out, it's hard to know which problems are independent of ZFC but not provably so.

Comment: Because there are many natural problems which are consistent only from large cardinals, and are independent assuming them. Others are consequences of having large cardinals, and are therefore just unprovable.

Comment: Émile Borel's conjecture on [strong measure zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_measure_zero_set) sets? The [normal Moore space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)) conjecture? Can Lebesgue measure on the line be extended to all subsets?

Comment: The examples by @bof are of the nature I referred to...